# Prove equation has solution by Brouwer fixed-point theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to prove that the following equation in $\mathbb{C}$ has solution. I have been asked to prove it using Brouwer fixed-point theorem but I don't really figure out how to apply it:

$$\frac{1}{53}z^4+\frac{1}{71}z^3-\frac{1}{73}z-z+\frac{1}{41}=0$$
I know I need to choose a continuous function to apply that $f(z)=z$ and I thought of $f(z)=\frac{1}{53}z^4+\frac{1}{71}z^3-\frac{1}{73}z-z+\frac{1}{41}$but working in a complex equation confuses me (of couse with the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra we are done but I was asked with Brouwer). In addition, we can't obviously apply Bolzano because the polynomial has an even degree. Anyone could help me? Thanks.

Comment: Your $f$ will not get you the fixed-point that you are looking for. Hint: try isolating the term in $z$. Secondly, for the fact that we're in $\mathbb{C}$, maybe seeing functions from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ as functions from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ in terms of real and imaginary parts would help you? Not sure if it would simplify the problem but it'd let you go back to the reals I suppose.

Comment: Which form of the Brouwer fixed-point theorem do you use?

Comment: The one which could be stated like "Every continuous function from a convex compact subset K of a Euclidean space to K itself has a fixed point"

Comment: Why don't you write $-\frac{74}{73} z$?

Answer (score 4):

You  can apply the Brouwer fixed-point theorem for $f(z) = \dfrac{73}{74}\left(\dfrac{1}{53}z^4 + \dfrac{1}{71}z^3 +  \dfrac{1}{41}\right)$. We have $\lvert f(z) \rvert \le \dfrac{73}{74}\left(\dfrac{1}{53}\lvert z \rvert^4 + \dfrac{1}{71}\lvert z \rvert ^3 +  \dfrac{1}{41}\right)$, thus for  $\lvert z \rvert \le 1$
$$\lvert f(z) \rvert \le \dfrac{73}{74}\left(\dfrac{1}{53} + \dfrac{1}{71}+  \dfrac{1}{41}\right) \le 1 .$$
This means that the closed unit disk $D$ is mapped by $f$ into itself.

Alternatively you can take $f(z) = \dfrac{1}{53}z^4 + \dfrac{1}{71}z^3 -  \dfrac{1}{73}z +  \dfrac{1}{41}$.